# Grant permission to user on AD for installing only drivers

Tags: active-directory, user-permissions, delegation

I need to grant permission to one user to install **only drivers**.

Is there such an option?  Or another option to grant permission?

Comment: It is Possible. But i dont want to be impolite, but we do not deliver the Answer without showing us, what you tried and what research has been done until you ask. please read [ask] - it take a while and should then update the question, what exactly does not work - i.e. there is a [other question](https://serverfault.com/questions/839929/gpo-allowing-domain-user-to-install-softwares-on-local-machines-without-being-ad?rq=1) which is similar like yours

Comment: Mט problem is that I am not offered how to set up to give permission to the user only to install drivers, so far I have only found how to give general permission to install all software

Comment: Yes, you have to select the allowed classes there. Another option would be to deploy the software via GPO if it's available as an .msi file. However, You must be a business administrator, and the environment must be within a business that question meet the serverfault requirements, else superuser.com would be the better way

Comment: There is not a role for "only installing drivers". No operating system has that or ever will have that.

Comment: not that I am aware of. Unless you are talking about a specific driver that has very clear document what permissions its installation needs, for installing any driver in general, the ability to install driver is almost always equal to local admin.

Comment: Please read https://www.beyondtrust.com/blog/entry/installing-device-drivers-as-a-standard-user-on-windows-7 which describes what to do to enable standard users to install drivers from selected locations that they themselves can write drivers to.